# Filter to only show specific object wiring

Tags: starbound

In Wiring mode, you can see how the input-output wire lines are displayed, as well as allowing you to connect from one object's input to another's output.

However, sometimes there is just too much wire pointing to an object where things starts to get real messy. (As shown in this picture)

[image: Image of messy wires]

Is there a way to filter which object's wire will be visible to me?

(Also, I am using a mod, FrackinUniverse, in case you were wondering about the some of the objects that does not exists in the vanilla build of the game.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in the current version, sorry.